# can't extract geo on mongoengine ListField(StringField()) - how come?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

i have no '2dshpere' in my code.
my class is simply

```
class DbBatch(Document):
  start_time = DateTimeField(required = True)
  duration_seconds = IntField()
  run_on_port = ListField(StringField())
  batch_name = StringField(required = True)
  batch_parameters = EmbeddedDocumentListField(DevicePortParameter)
  statistics = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Statistics)
```

and i'm just doing

```
reg0_batch0 = DbBatch()
reg0_batch0.batch_name = 'reg0_batch2'
reg0_batch0.run_on_port = ['0']
```

and i get error on saving the document - **why ???? there is no 2d sphere or anything interesting in this simple list**

```
# Saving to DB 
reg0_batch0.save()

# output 
......
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\document.py", line 398, in save
raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))
OperationError: Could not save document 
(Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('57d64f926151394b5c740fea'),
start_time: new Date(1473673632148), run_on_port: [ 0 ], 
batch_name: "reg0_batch2", batch_parameters: [], statistics: [] }  
Point must only contain numeric elements)
```

And when clearing the ListField i do not get any error

```
reg0_batch0.run_on_port = []
reg0_batch0.save()

# good response - saved into DB 
Out[16]: <DbBatch: DbBatch object>
```

**Any Ideas?**

BTW - same result with ListField(IntField())

Answer (score 0):

I cleared collection and redo - now there is no error - do not know why the error was there in the first place - but anyhow it is solved